# How to Improve this Visual Studio Post-Build Event that is using ajaxmin.exe

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010 post-build event to minify my JavaScript files.  The problem is every time I add a new JavaScript file I have to update the post build event.  What I want to do is make the script a bit more flexible.

**Directory structure:**


\Scripts\

- Script1.debug.js
- Script2.debug.js
- Script3.debug.js

**Here is my script's current state:**

```
ajaxmin.exe "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script1.debug.js" -out "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script1.js" -clobber
ajaxmin.exe "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script2.debug.js" -out "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script2.js" -clobber
ajaxmin.exe "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script3.debug.js" -out "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Script3.js" -clobber
```

I want this script to find every *.debug.js file minify it and output it to *.js.  How do I achieve this?

Script1.debug.js --> Script1.js 
Script2.debug.js --> Script2.js 
Script3.debug.js --> Script3.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a post build event.  After installing the tool, an MSBuild task was added that runs the minifier automatically for a .js file in your project.  You need a bit of minor surgery to the project file.  The details are explained in this [blog post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/16/using-the-new-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off

for /r "js\" %%i IN (*.js) do (
    call :Sub %%~fi
)

:Sub
set debug=%*
set release=%debug:.debug=%
AjaxMin.exe -hc "%debug%" -o "%release%" -clobber
```

Find all javascript (*.js) files in folder "js\" then remove ".debug" from filename (actually replace it with null string) and run AjaxMin

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch script file to do the task and call the batch file from your PostBuild event.

Comment: Sheen, this script is already in a batch file.  I just need to know how to write the script required to solve the problem described.  It isn't a matter of where the script will live (batch or build event textbox).